# How can I use a pointer to a pointer in c#?

Tags: c#, pointers, ffmpeg

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2012 to call a function that is included in a set of external libraries that my project requires.  The function requires a double pointer to be passed in but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.  Single pointers work great for me.  I am using the unsafe keyword.

```
AVFormatContext _file = new AVFormatContext();

fixed (AVFormatContext* p_file = &_file)
{
   avformat_alloc_output_context2(&p_file,null,null,filename);
}
```

VS is complaining about the "&p_file" syntax with the error of "Cannot take the address of a read-only local variable".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to declare `avformat_alloc_output_context2` with a `ref` parameter instead of using `&`.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  The error states:  Cannot pass 'p_file' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'fixed variable'

Comment: I don't think you have posted enough code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't take the address of `p_file` because `p_file` is read-only inside the fixed block. If you could take its address then this would be possible:

```
fixed (AVFormatContext* p_file = &_file)
{
   AVFormatContext** ppf = &p_file;
   *ppf = null; // Just changed the contents of a read-only variable!
```

Therefore you have to take the address of something you *can* change:

```
fixed (AVFormatContext* p_file = &_file)
{
   AVFormatContext* pf = p_file;
   AVFormatContext** ppf = &pf;
```

And now we're all good; changing `*ppf` does not change `p_file`.